# Compiling Tensorflow with a custom Clang + Libc++ (instead of stdlibc++)

Tags: c++, tensorflow, llvm, clang++, bazel

I am trying to compile tensorflow with a custom clang/llvm toolchain and using clang's native libc++ (instead of borrowing Gcc's stdlibc++).

It looks like bazel plain assumes that every clang will use Gcc's libraries because I get these errors:

```
$ bazel build --cxxopt=-std=c++11 --cxxopt=-stdlib=libc++ tensorflow:libtensorflow.so
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: From Compiling 
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/embed.cc [for host]:
external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/embed.cc:37:12: 
warning: unused variable 'output_file' [-Wunused-const-variable]
const char output_file[] = "well_known_types_embed.cc";
            ^
1 warning generated.
ERROR: /home/hbucher/.cache/bazel/_bazel_hbucher/ad427c7fddd5b68de5e1cfaa7cd8c8cc/external/com_googlesource_code_re2/BUILD:11:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '@com_googlesource_code_re2//:re2':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'external/com_googlesource_code_re2/re2/bitstate.cc':
  '/home/hbucher/install/include/c++/v1/stddef.h'
  '/home/hbucher/install/include/c++/v1/__config'
```

I tried to hack into tools/cpp/CROSSTOOL inside bazel as some posts suggested to add the line

```
cxx_builtin_include_directory: "/home/hbucher/install/include/c++/v1"
```

but to no avail, it does not seem to make any difference.

Then I tried to follow a bazel tutorial to create a custom toolchain. The text does not help much because they are actually writing a cross tool while what I am trying to do is to tweak the existing host rules and somehow bazel seems to undo every attempt I try to tweak its parameters.

I have got to the point that is currently in my github repository https://github.com/HFTrader/BazelCustomToolchain

However it does not compile and I cannot even figure out how to start debugging this message.

```
$  bazel build --crosstool_top=@hbclang//:toolchain tensorflow:libtensorflow.so                                                                                             
.....................                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ERROR: The crosstool_top you specified was resolved to 
'@hbclang//:toolchain', which does not contain a CROSSTOOL file. You can 
use a crosstool from the depot by specifying its label.
INFO: Elapsed time: 2.216s
```

I have appended these lines to my tensorflow/WORKSPACE

```
new_local_repository(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  name="hbclang",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  path="/home/hbucher/BazelCustomToolchain",                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  build_file = "/home/hbucher/BazelCustomToolchain/BUILD",      
)
```

I have asked this question on bazel's google groups but they redirected me to stackoverflow. At this point I am about to give up.

Have someone attempted to do this or I'm breaking ground here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Solved. Not in the intended way but it works for me.

```
export INSTALL_DIR="$HOME/install"
export CC=$INSTALL_DIR/bin/clang
export CXX=$INSTALL_DIR/bin/clang++
export CXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++ -L$INSTALL_DIR/lib"
export LDFLAGS="-L$INSTALL_DIR/lib -lm -lrt"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$INSTALL_DIR/lib"
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git tensorflow-github
cd tensorflow-github
mkdir build-tmp && cd build-tmp
cmake ../tensorflow/contrib/cmake/
make -j4
```

Easy as 1-2-3 with cmake

Comment: yes, unfortunately they dropped the CMake support completely

Comment: @Slava no they didn't ?

Comment: @tanishq-banyal yes they did. I do not see a cmakelists in their github repository. Only crappy bazel build files.

Comment: @Slava oh yes, I misremembered, they only have CMake support for tflite

Answer (score 2):

[2020-05-24: Edit to make the answer up to date.]

TLDR: To build a project with Bazel with a specific Clang binary, and with libc++, this works for me (where `INSTALL_DIR` is where I've installed llvm):

```sh
CC="$INSTALL_DIR/bin/clang" \
BAZEL_CXXOPTS="-stdlib=libc++:-isystem$INSTALL_DIR/include" \
BAZEL_LINKOPTS="-stdlib=libc++" \
BAZEL_LINKLIBS="-L$INSTALL_DIR/lib:-Wl,-rpath,$INSTALL_DIR/lib:-lc++:-lm" \
bazel test //...
```

Background:

You can use `--repo_env` option, e.g. `--repo_env=CC=clang`, to put these defaults into your project- or system-wide .bazelrc.

This approach uses Bazel's C++ toolchain autoconfiguration which doesn't attempt to declare all the toolchain inputs in BUILD files. This is to simplify the configuration for the user. Therefore whenever you modify the C++ toolchain in a way that Bazel cannot know about (rebuild llvm etc.), you have to run `bazel clean --expunge` to flush the cache and rerun the autoconfiguration the next time.

The robust solution to specifying C++ toolchain in Bazel is to use the CcToolchainConfigInfo. See the documentation at https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html and https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cc-toolchain-config-reference.html.

Comment: Well the Crosstool file is exactly there for this reason - to define the C++ toolchain, so Bazel doesn't have to hardcode anything. This allows us to have the same quite platform-independent BUILD files that work on linux/mac/windows and all the platform dependent logic is encapsulated in Crosstool. So it is actually more robust that the tools you mention provide. The price we pay is the added complexity, and we are actively working on making it simpler. We're not there yet completely. And I'm writing better documentation for this very use case right now.

Comment: Your rhetoric and insults make me very unmotivated to help you (as we're not obliged to do so!) . Please describe your problems clearly and one in a time. So far we solved issues with your crosstool and its build file, then fixed the local_repository issue. Are you talking about path to clang binary itself or include directories? I assume it's the latter, and cxx_builtin_include_directory message should be the solution there. If it's not, I don't understand your problem and then please elaborate.

Comment: Look, I found another way - I am compiling tensorflow with whatever GCC is in the box and building an application from within  the bazel build such that I can interface using shared memory. Not really ideal but it gets the job done for now. If I come through a solution I will post here.

Comment: No matter what I place there - it just cannot find the toolchain. I run with `bazel build --crosstool_top=@hbclang//:toolchain tensorflow:libtensorflow_all.so --cpu=linux_x86_64` and place `cpu="linux_x86_64"` and `compiler="clang"` in the toolchain but bazel still gives me `cc_toolchain_suite '@hbclang//:toolchain' does not contain a toolchain for CPU 'linux_x86_64' and compiler 'clang'.`

Comment: This did not work for me with local LLVM 10.0.1 installation and the TF master branch. I am still getting a binary that is linked with libstdc++