# Configure bazel toolchain without modifying project/workspace

Tags: bazel

I have a Bazel project (the new tcmalloc) I'm trying to integrate into a typical GNU Make project that uses it's own build of compiler/libc++. The goal is to not fork the upstream project.

If I pass all the C++ options correctly to bazel (one set of which is `-nostdinc++ -I<path to libc++>`), Bazel is uhappy `The include path '/home/vlovich/myproject/deps/toolchain/libc++/trunk/include' references a path outside of the execution root.` (tcmalloc is a git submodule sibling @ `deps/tcmalloc`). It's possible to get this "working" by giving Bazel a custom script to invoke as the compiler that injects those flags so that Bazel never sees them. However, I'd like to just define a toolchain to work properly.

I've read all the documentation I could find on this topic but it's not clear to me how to glue all these docs together.

Specifically not really clear where I should place the toolchain definition files or how to tell Bazel to find those definitions. Is there a way to give bazel a directory that it uses to find toolchain definitions? Am I expected to create a top-level WORKSPACE @ `/home/vlovich/myproject` & register `tcmalloc` and my toolchain there, & then invoke bazel from `/home/vlovich/myproject` instead of `/home/vlovich/myproject/deps/tcmalloc`?

Answer (score 0):

Toolchain support is rather complicated, and it is hard to understand, if you are not a bazel maintainer.

You can use `CC` and `CXX` environment variables to set a different compiler like: `CC=your_c_compiler CXX=your_c++_compiler bazel build ...`. You can write your own custom script wrapper which will act as a normal C++ compiler

That `-I<path to libc++>` does not work, because all normal include paths have to be defined in `srcs` attribute or via dependencies indicated by the `deps` attribute. For system-wide dependencies use `-isystem` Read more about it https://stackoverflow.com/a/44061589/4638604

Comment: Hmm.... even with -isystem it's complaining about referencing a path outside the execution root. Granted not for libc++, but for a different library. I would have thought Bazel would treat all `-isystem` the same?

FWIW I'm happy to consider myself enough of a Bazel expert to try to use a toolchain. The two blockers I encountered was how to specify the toolchain when building a 3p project & bazel crashes when I give it a relative toolchain path (& I'm not sure how to compute the absolute path regardless of the user's home directory).

Comment: (I can elide the other library from the compiler path - just curious)